# Sort a List of object with 3 diferent numbers

Tags: java, android, arrays, java-8

I have a list of objects

```
List<Values> mList = new Arraylist...
```

where a, b and c have different values which I don't know. I need to return the position of largest value of a and b and the smallest value of c. How to organize this list so that position 0 has the corresponding entry?

I tried something like

```
mList.sort(p1, p2 -> Math.max(p1.getValueA, Math.min(p1.getValueB, p2.getValueC))`
```

with no results...

(The values are int)

Comment: If you only need the one object that has the largest a and b and the smallest c, then there’s no reason to sort the entire list. Use [`Collections.max(Collection, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator)) with a suitable comparator, for example the one from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort in descending order by the first property, then in descending order by the second property, then in ascending order by the third property. You can do so by chaining `Comparator`s.

```
list.sort (Comparator.comparing (Values::getValueA).reversed ()
                     .thenComparing (Comparator.comparing (Values::getValueB).reversed ())
                     .thenComparing(Values::getValueC));
```

Comment: This helped, but c still returns the largest value... Log:

`A: 10 - C: 5 - B: 15`
`A: 7 - C: 4 - B: 11`
`A: 6 - C: 0 - B: 6`
`A: 5 - C: 1 - B: 6`
`A: 5 - C: 1 - B: 6`
`A: 4 - C: 2 - B: 6`

Comment: @AlekSan Well, it first orders by A in descending order. Only for entries having same A it orders by B, and only for entries of same A,B it orders by C. Your largest A is 10, and  there's only one object with A==10, so that one will be first in the sorted list.

Comment: It should probably be `comparingInt` or `comparingDouble` depending on the type of `valueA`. Similarly `thenComparingInt`, etc.

Comment: @OleV.V. It passes compilation as is. I just tried with `comparingInt` and `thenComparingInt`, and it did not compile.

Comment: @OleV.V. OP wrote they are `int`. I created a basic `Values` class with those 3 methods to test compilation.

Comment: @Eran Yes, the logic is returning as it should, but would it be possible for it to return the value of a and b that is closest to the maximum where c is closest to the minimum? Let me know if this got confusing.

Comment: I did the same. This compiles fine: `mList.sort (Comparator.comparingInt(Values::getValueA).reversed () .thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(Values::getValueB).reversed ()) .thenComparingInt(Values::getValueC));` (sorry about the bad readability in the comment). So `thenComparing` without `Int` before `(Comparator.comparingInt(...` and with `Int` in the other places. What you get from neglecting this is needless boxing and unboxing. You still get the expected result in the end.

Comment: @AlekSan You'll have to define some function that behaves like the required behavior. For example, you can order by `C/A*B`, so smaller Cs will push you to the beginning of the List and large As and Bs will also push you to the beginning of the List.

Comment: @OleV.V. which Java version are you using? I tried your code and get `The type Values does not define getValueA(T) that is applicable here` and `The method comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Values::getValueB)`

Comment: OK. But this has already helped me a lot. I believe I can work on the code to make it work the way I need it to. Many thanks to both of you for your help. I believe that if I order by the largest value of b and then by the smallest value of c, by logic, a will be the closest to the maximum.

Comment: Interesting. I used openjdk-18.0.1.1. But it compiles fine with java-11-openjdk too. [See it compile online with Java 12](https://ideone.com/xDZbon) (that program does nothing sensible whatsoever, but it compiles).

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm using Java 11 on eclipse. (java-11-openjdk-11.0.8-2)

Comment: I haven’t guessed what you have done wrong. On my Eclipse version 2019-03 (4.11.0) the code from [my link](https://ideone.com/xDZbon) also compiles and runs fine no matter if using jdk-11.0..3 or 1.8.0_101.